# Telerik Kendo Scheduler Selected Event Details

Tags: javascript, telerik, scheduler, telerik-mvc, kendo-scheduler

This is regarding Telerik Kendo (MVC) Scheduler control. When I double click any specific event, I would like to get some selective details for that event, like Description, Start Time, IsAllDay.

Not all the data. This is because I want to take all this selected data for the event and show it on a different page, where I may then perform some edit/update. I know the Kendo scheduler offers a pop-up mode to edit data but we don't need that in our application flow. That is the catch.

Is it at all possible?

I am new to Telerik Kendo MVC controls and I have no idea what or how. My knowledge on this matters is less than 7 days. The resources I searched around are mostly talking about client-side js code. The control itself is rendered through JS in those examples, as opposed to @Html.Kendo(). A scheduler in my case. It is not related to my need.

Can you give me some hints? Can you please show me how. And most importantly, is it at all possible. Could you confirm that...

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an editor template, it will substitute the default template that is displayed when you double click an event.

For this you have to:-

-Add the editable property to your scheduler control

```
  .Editable(editable => editable.TemplateName("CustomEditorTemplate"))
```

-Add a partial view with the same name as TemplateName specified above.

-Add the model and html for the selective details to the partial view

-If you are allowing any edits on the popup add the data source property for Update

```
.Update("ActionName", "ControllerName")
```

This is the editor template [API Reference](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/SchedulerBuilder#editablesystemactionkendomvcuifluentschedulereditablesettingsbuildert)

Comment: hi @MarissaFernandes thanks for replying. I am going to check out these things you have advised. Thing is, I am so new [and clueless] to Telerik Kendo, I am not 100% that I even understand your answer properly although I am pretty sure they are helpful. I will keep you posted on what I manage to achieve with this, thanks so much,